# Omit Elements of Name "Applicant"

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a file with structure:

```
<root>
    <stuff>...</stuff>
    <whatever>
        <Applicant Aha="blah" />
        <Applicant />
        <Applicant />
    </whatever>
</root>
```

The long-term requirement is that empty (no content or attributes) Applicant nodes go away.

However, my current frustration is that my transform is not doing what I expect it to do, which is omit Applicant nodes entirely.

Transform 1 (identity.xsl):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Transform 2 (applicant.xsl):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:import href="identity.xsl"/>   
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Applicant" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Currently this outputs everything in the source file, including the nefarious Applicant nodes. WHY?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you definitely applying the "applicant.xsl" to the XML, not the "identity.xsl"? Also, is your XML sample truly representative, or does it have namespace declarations in? Thanks!